# Scala Mockito Guice and Partial Mocking .... methods get called twice

Tags: scala, mockito, guice, scalatest

I have the following code written in Scala, Guice, Mockito and ScalaTest

```
import javax.inject.Singleton
import com.google.inject.Inject
@Singleton
class TestPartialMock @Inject()(t1: Test1, t2: Test2) {
   def test3() = "I do test3"
   def workHorse() : List[String] = {
      println("+++++ came inside ++++++++")
      List(t1.test1(), t2.test2(), test3())
   }
}


class MainModule extends ScalaModule {
   override def configure() = {
      bind[Test1]
      bind[Test2]
      bind[TestPartialMock]
   }
}
```

and I have written unit test cases with partial mocking

```
class PartialMockTest extends FunSpec with Matchers {
   describe("we are testing workhorse but mock test3") {
      it("should return mock for test3") {
         val module = new TestModule
         val injector = Guice.createInjector(module)
         val tpm = injector.getInstance(classOf[TestPartialMock])
         val result = tpm.workHorse()
         result should contain ("i do test2")
         result should contain ("i do test1")
         result should contain ("I am mocked")
         result should not contain ("I do test3")
      }
   }
}

class TestModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule with MockitoSugar {
   override def configure() = {
      val module = new MainModule()
      val injector = Guice.createInjector(module)
      val realobject = injector.getInstance(classOf[TestPartialMock])
      val x = spy(realobject)
      when(x.test3()).thenReturn("I am mocked")
      when(x.workHorse()).thenCallRealMethod()
      bind(classOf[TestPartialMock]).toInstance(x)
   }
}
```

My tests are successful and I can see that it mocks the right set of methods and calls the actual implementation of the right set of methods. BUT when I look at the output I see

```
info] Compiling 5 Scala sources to /Users/IdeaProjects/GuicePartialMock/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/IdeaProjects/GuicePartialMock/target/scala-2.12/test-classes...
+++++ came inside ++++++++
+++++ came inside ++++++++
[info] PartialMockTest:
[info] we are testing workhorse but mock test3
[info] - should return mock for test3
[info] Run completed in 2 seconds, 92 milliseconds.
```

Why am I seeing the print statement `came inside` twice?

Edit::

Based on advice of Tavian ... this is the final code which worked

```
class TestModule extends AbstractModule with ScalaModule with MockitoSugar {
   override def configure() = {
      val module = new MainModule()
      val injector = Guice.createInjector(module)
      val realobject = injector.getInstance(classOf[TestPartialMock])
      val x = spy(realobject)
      when(x.test3()).thenReturn("I am mocked")
      bind(classOf[TestPartialMock]).toInstance(x)
   }
}
```

Comment: For Mockito spies, `when(x.workHorse())` will have already invoked the real `workHorse()` method.  In fact, there's no need for `.thenCallRealMethod()` as that's the default behaviour of spies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For spies, you need to be careful of expressions like

```
when(x.workHorse()).thenCallRealMethod()
```

because `x.workHorse()` really is invoked in this expression!  `x` doesn't "know" that it's inside a `when()` call, as the expression is lowered into something like this:

```
tmp1 = x.workHorse();
tmp2 = when(tmp1);
tmp3 = tmp2.thenCallRealMethod();
```

Instead, you can write

```
doCallRealMethod().when(x).workHorse()
```

which will suppress the invocation of the real `workHorse()` implementation.

**But**, you don't need to do any of this for this example—calling real methods is the default behaviour of spies.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. I edited my post above with the new code. But still I see two invocations.

Comment: But you didn't take my suggestion (`doCallRealMethod().when(x).workHorse()`)

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned in the question title, you have a combination of 3 technologies. Actually 4 technologies including build tool that is used to run the test. You can isolate the problem by

1) Remove Guice and instantiate everything directly

2) Run code as a simple App instead of running as a test by sbt/gradle/maven.

Also it makes sense to print stack trace together with a `came inside` message to find a caller.

Comment: Everything works with Guice is removed. the whole point of the thead is that I want to do it with Guice. That is the crux of the problem. Otherwise it is simple.